# Trying to mount a host volume on a Docker container on Windows. What is the source folder relative to?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume, docker-run

I'm having trouble on trying to mount a volume to my docker container.

Here is my project structure

```
cloudRun
  distService/
    index.js
  Dockerfile
  package.json    // THIS IS THE package.json FOR THE DOCKER IMAGE

package.json      // THIS IS MY MAIN PROJECT package.json
```

In my main project `package.json` I have the following scripts:

```
"docker-run": "./scripts/docker/docker-run.sh",
"docker-inspect": "docker exec -ti hello-world sh"   // THIS IS USED TO INSPECT THE RUNNING CONTAINER
```

**docker-run.sh**

```
// STOPS ALL CONTAINERS
// REMOVES ALL CONTAINERS
// REMOVES ALL IMAGES

// BUILDS A NEW IMAGE FROM SCRATCH
docker build --tag hello-world:latest ./cloudRun

// TRYING TO RUN THE CONTAINER WITH A MOUNTED /distService VOLUME
docker run --name hello-world -p 3000:3000 -v //distService:/distService hello-world:latest
```

This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12-slim

WORKDIR /

COPY ./package.json ./package.json

RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT npm start
```

It's all working. Except for the fact that the container is seeing `/distService` as an empty folder.

I know this because when I open a new terminal window and run:

```
npm run docker-inspect
```

I get to enter the folders and `ls` them. And this is what I'm getting: there is a `distService` folder, but the `ls` command comes back empty. PS: I did a `ls` on `node_modules` just to show that it works and the `distService` is indeed empty.

[image]

**QUESTION**

When I pass `-v //folder:/folder`, what is the source folder relative to? How can I be sure that I'm picking the right folder?

**Environment:**

```
Windows 10.
Docker for Windows installed
Docker Engine v19.03.13
```

**UPDATE**

I ran the container and inspected it with: `docker inspect <CONTAINER_ID>` to see what folder is being mounted. But it didn't help much. This is what came back:

```
"HostConfig": {
  "Binds": [
    "//distService/:/distService/"
],

// OTHER STUFF

"Mounts": [
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/distService",         // WHAT IS THIS PATH RELATIVE TO ?
    "Destination": "/distService",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  }
],
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I had to do to make it work.

Basicallly I had to put the full absolute path starting from `c:/`.

```
-v c:/Users/my-user/my-project/distService:/distService
```

Full command:

```
docker run --name hello-world -p 3000:3000 -v c:/Users/USER/my-project/distService:/distService hello-world:latest
```

I had the idea after I found this on the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only):

[image]

Comment: In windows, a double slash is needed at the beginning of the path to indicate the working directory. Just to work use like this ``docker run -v //$(PWD)/folder:/folder ...``

Answer (score 0):

With `docker run` local folder paths are always relative to the root.
To get a relative path either use the `PWD` environment variable:

`docker run -v $(PWD)/folder:/folder ...`

Or, docker-compose does support relative paths if they start with a period:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
    - ./folder:/www
```

Comment: `docker run -v $(PWD)/folder:/folder ...` is not working. At least not on Windows. Haven't tested with `docker-compose` yet.

Comment: ah. its been a while since I used Windows. Can't recall the env variable that holds the current directory in it - it will probably be different and may contain spaces so wrapping everything in ""s will be important.

Comment: In windows, a double slash is needed at the beginning of the path to indicate the working directory. Just to work use like this ``docker run -v //$(PWD)/folder:/folder ...``. Work for me with Git Bash